# NameError when trying to import variables from another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, python-import

I am trying to import variables from one python file to another. What I am trying:

```
# myfile1.py

x = 5
y = 2


# myfile2.py

from myfile1 import *

print(myfile1.x)
print(myfile1.y)
```

I am getting a name error, 'NameError: name 'x' is not defined'. The two files are in the same folder. I have also tried different variations of the import statement like:

```
import myfile1

from myfile1 import x, y
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Either leave off the `import *`, or access them directly as `x`, `y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing variables from another file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710477/importing-variables-from-another-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import functions from another file it's like importing any other module.
When importing a module The basic syntax is `import module`, in which case your code would be correct. But you imported the other common way `from module import *`. That imports the file in a way that allows you to not include the prefix, so just `print(x)` and `print(y)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only importing the resources so you don't need to prefix my file:

```
print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just do :

```
print(x)
print(y)
```